# MySql (popup message box if failed to insert data)

Tags: mysql, database, insert

Hi I have a code that print out some message if the data are successfully inserted into database.

This is the code:

```
  if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
    echo "Record saved!";
```

How do I make it so that instead of opening a new page and print them, I need them to just display a message box indicating whether it is successful or not.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('failed!')</script>";
    }else{
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
    }
```

Use this to get a message box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   echo '<script language="javascript">';
   echo 'alert("Record saving failed")';
   echo '</script>';
}else{
   echo '<script language="javascript">';
   echo 'alert("Record saved")';
   echo '</script>';
 }
```